# Error during click on settings button

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to Android Development and was trying to get a Settings menu to show up on my app.

The XML file for Preferences is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:title="@string/settings">
<SwitchPreference
    android:title="Switch Preference"
    android:key="switchpref"
    android:switchTextOn="ON"
    android:switchTextOff="OFF"
    android:summary="Night Mode"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:disableDependentsState="false"
    />

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

The Main Class file is here, where I try to switch to the Settings Activity

```
package com.example.notepad;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
         Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,      PreferencesFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

The Preferences Java file that displays the Settings menu is here

```
package com.example.notepad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PreferencesFragment extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.xml.preferences);
}

}
```

I can't figure out why an error occurs. It only displays the generic "Unfortunately, the application has stopped" when I click on the Settings button

The Log file is here

```
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notepad/com.example.notepad.PreferencesFragment}:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class  PreferenceScreen
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at com.example.notepad.PreferencesFragment.onCreate(PreferencesFragment.java:12)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  ... 11 more
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.PreferenceScreen
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
 01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  at          android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-17 19:49:28.795: E/AndroidRuntime(756):  ... 20 more
```

EDIT - My AndroidManifest.xml file  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.notepad"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
  >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.notepad.HomeScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".PreferencesFragment" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use PreferenceScreen inside Activity (PreferencesFragment extends Activity). Read doc and use it right way.

> PreferenceScreen can appear in two places:
>
> When a PreferenceActivity points to this, it is used as the root and is not shown (only the contained preferences are shown).
>
> When it appears inside another preference hierarchy, it is shown and serves as the gateway to another screen of preferences (either by showing another screen of preferences as a Dialog or via a startActivity(android.content.Intent) from the getIntent()). The children of this PreferenceScreen are NOT shown in the screen that this PreferenceScreen is shown in. Instead, a separate screen will be shown when this preference is clicked.

Comment: Will I have to use Fragments instead of Activity then? I added my AndroidManifest file in OP. Not sure if it is right

Comment: [reread this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)
You can use PreferenceFragment or PreferenceActivity.